# example traefik to docker with http work but not with https

Tags: traefik

I'm trying to make a traefik's POC. With http works perfect but not with https.

Let's encrypt certificates generated by traefik isn't ok and I don't know why.
I hope you can help me, thanks so much in advance.

I hope too it will help the community to have a complete simple example that works

```
root@ubuntu:~/traefik# ls -lt | more
total 8
-rw------- 1 root root   0 Nov 23 06:08 acme.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 698 Nov 23 05:57 traefik.toml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 399 Nov 23 05:56 docker-compose.yml
```

The traefik.toml configuration file..

```
root@ubuntu:~/traefik# cat traefik.toml

logLevel = "DEBUG"

[traefikLog]
  filePath = "./traefik.log"
  format   = "json"

[accessLog]
  filePath = "./access.log"
  format = "json"

[web]
# Port for the status page
address = ":8080"


defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]

[acme]
email = "xpoveda@gmail.com"
storage = "acme.json"
onHostRule = true
caServer = "https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
entryPoint = "https"

  [[acme.domains]]
    main = "escalamas.com"
    sans = ["test.escalamas.com"]


[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
watch = true
exposedbydefault = false
```

And docker-compose for create a traefik service...

```
root@ubuntu:~/traefik# cat docker-compose.yml
version: '2'
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik
    command: --docker
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
      - "./traefik.toml:/traefik.toml"
      - "./acme.json:/acme.json"
      - "./traefik.log:/traefik.log"
      - "./access.log:/access.log"
    networks:
      - default
```

On other hand I have an simply dockerized application "hello world" in python ,Dockerfile and Docker compose.

```
root@ubuntu:~/apps# more start.py
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello " + request.host


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=False,host='0.0.0.0')



root@ubuntu:~/apps# more Dockerfile
FROM python:2.7
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN pip install flask
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["start.py"]


root@ubuntu:~/apps# more docker-compose.yml
version: '2'

services:
    test:
        build: .
        labels:
          - "traefik.enabled=true"
          - "traefik.backend=test"
          - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:test.escalamas.com"
          - "traefik.port=5000"
        networks:
          - "traefik_default"
        restart: always
networks:
    traefik_default:
        external:
            name: traefik_default
```

When I run everything...

```
cat /dev/null > /root/traefik/acme.json

cd /root/traefik
docker-compose up -d

Creating traefik_traefik_1 ...
Creating traefik_traefik_1 ... done


cd /root/apps
docker-compose up -d

Creating apps_test_1 ...
Creating apps_test_1 ... done
```

And when I execute with http all ok

```
root@ubuntu:~/traefik# curl --resolve test.escalamas.com:80:127.0.0.1 http://test.escalamas.com/
Hello test.escalamas.com
```

But https error in certificate: common name: TRAEFIK DEFAULT CERT (does not match 'test.escalamas.com') and 404 error in page

```
root@ubuntu:~/traefik# curl -v --resolve test.escalamas.com:443:127.0.0.1 https://test.escalamas.com/ --insecure
* Added test.escalamas.com:443:127.0.0.1 to DNS cache
* Hostname test.escalamas.com was found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to test.escalamas.com (127.0.0.1) port 443 (#0)
* found 149 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 593 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_RSA_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*        server certificate verification SKIPPED
*        server certificate status verification SKIPPED
*        common name: TRAEFIK DEFAULT CERT (does not match 'test.escalamas.com')
*        server certificate expiration date OK
*        server certificate activation date OK
*        certificate public key: RSA
*        certificate version: #3
*        subject: CN=TRAEFIK DEFAULT CERT
*        start date: Fri, 23 Nov 2018 14:16:22 GMT
*        expire date: Sat, 23 Nov 2019 14:16:22 GMT
*        issuer: CN=TRAEFIK DEFAULT CERT
*        compression: NULL
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: test.escalamas.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Date: Fri, 23 Nov 2018 14:19:03 GMT
< Content-Length: 19
<
404 page not found
* Connection #0 to host test.escalamas.com left intact
```

The acme.json is not empty but the certificate is not valid

```
root@ubuntu:~/traefik# cat acme.json
{
  "Account": {
    "Email": "xpoveda@gmail.com",
    "Registration": {
      "body": {
        "status": "valid",
        "contact": [
          "mailto:xpoveda@gmail.com"
        ]
      },
      "uri": "https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/acct/7415315"
    },
    "PrivateKey": "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",
    "KeyType": "4096"
  },
  "Certificates": null,
  "HTTPChallenges": null,
  "TLSChallenges": null
```

In addition, the log files are created as folders, not as files and I don't know how view the traefik.log beacause the classic docker run -it ssh not work with this image.

```
root@ubuntu:~/traefik# ls -lt | more
total 20
-rw------- 1 root root 3534 Nov 23 06:16 acme.json
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 23 06:16 access.log
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 23 06:16 traefik.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  698 Nov 23 05:57 traefik.toml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  399 Nov 23 05:56 docker-compose.yml
```

thanks so much!!

Xavier.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's because this line in your `traefik.toml` file.

```
caServer = "https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
```

You are using the staging servers to get your certificate. If you delete this line, you will negotiate a production-ready certificate with Let's Encrypt.

More information: https://letsencrypt.org/docs/staging-environment/